# Flume can't access s3 to write the file java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid hostname in URI s3://ACCESSKEY:SECRETKEY/@bucket

Tags: flume

Flume is install on amazon EC2 (Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0.20190514 x86_64 HVM gp2) Flume version: 1.9

I try to use a local as a sink the copy works perfectly. But when I use S3 as a sink, I hit the invalid hostname in URI problem. 
I doubled check my access key and secret key, they are all correct.

I tried to use s3n:// it did not work

```
# example.conf: A single-node Flume configuration

# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

a1.sources.r1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
a1.sources.r1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
a1.sources.r1.kafka.topics = testflume
a1.sources.r1.kafka.consumer.group.id = flumeconsumer


a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = s3://AWSACCESSKEY:AWSSECRETKEY@bucket/path
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = event
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval = 10


# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 1000

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

The error

```
[ERROR - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:459)] process failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid hostname in URI s3://AWSACCESSKEY:AWSSECRETKEY@bucket/path/event.1558997927667.tmp
```

I expect flume to authenticate successfully in S3 and write the files

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using s3a://?
But it is good practice to assign a role to EC2 instance and give permission to S3 for that role, instead of providing AWS Access and secret keys. Once you setup that you can the path as `s3a://bucket_name/path/../`